# My Application does not visible in play store from Tablet with no rear camera

Tags: android, camera

I have an app in PlayStore  , it accesses Camera  feature and Geo location .The app is visible when I search it form Phone but not in Tablet (no rear Camera) .I have made the user feature  required false in the manifest.xml but still I cant find it in the play store .

My manifest file for app

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

when you specifically search for your app from the tablet does it display as unsupported hardware or give an incorrect OS version error?

Comment: I found my solution .I have used aapt tool to check how play store restrict my app and I got the following ..
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps','requested android.permis
.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission' . .

Because of this  internally it  was filtering devices which have GPS but in my TAB LENOVO 1000L  doesnt have GPS .
SO I made  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
after making this change I can search my APP in   Play Store form my TABLET .